# How can I make micro-scale water?

Tags: building, micro-scale

This is totally boring:

[image: A blue baseplate.]

How can I add some variance to it that helps to distinguish a rippling lake from a raging ocean from a fast-moving river, while keeping a look that's appropriate for micro-scale landscapes?

Comment: It's boring, but when you need to cover a few tables with ocean, you get used to it very fast.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 1x1x2/3 slopes would be ideal for making waves, etc.:

[image: 54200 1x1x2/3 - Blue] and [image: 54200 1x1x2/3 - White] or the 1x2 options.

Along with some blue tiles you could make some great waves:

[image: Microscale Waves]

Obviously, if you don't want them breaking, keep the white fronts blue.

Also, if you have some Navy blue tiles you can create currents of colder water - if you've ever watched large bodies of water you'll notice they have strips of different shades running through them.

Stick to tiles on the plate rather than the 2/3s height for lakes, or for some good ripples use the Round Dish 2x2 Inverted:

[image: Round Dish 2x2 Inverted - Blue]

Comment: Transparent parts (slopes, tiles) work very well too

Comment: Good call @joubarc

Comment: Put the transparent on top of the blue baseplate and use different colors of transparent... you can get some very interesting effects that way

Answer (score 3):

Try using combos of Trans-clear and Trans-blue studs to make a nice, clear foaming water affect. Studs can be bought in extreme masses  on Bricklink for like, 1¢. So there's no trouble.

Answer (score 2):

- Here is David Lee using transparent bricks to create [nice waves](http://www.mocpages.com/image_zoom.php?mocid=289695&id=/user_images/65528/1317522483m_DISPLAY.jpg)
- Here is Mark of Falworth using another technique involving [loose bricks of different colors](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mark-of-falworth/6555873241/in/set-72157628529107563).

Comment: The second one is particularly impressive, but both of those are minifig scale, not microscale.

Comment: oops. I somehow skipped "microscale". I'd use the same techniques regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Use a blue stud and put a flat round Lego brick on top of it to make the beautiful ripples.